# How to execute EntityFramework CLI commands programmatically in .NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

How to run those `dotnet.exe ef <command>` commands programmatically in **.NET Core**?

For example to add migration I'm running in terminal `dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration` and it will indeed create Migrations folder with migration classes, but to create new Migration (for example) programmatically from C# code?

Don't suggest `Process.Start("cmd bla-bla")` since code should be cross-platform and that `dotnet ef` runs some code from some EntityFrameworkCore package anyway. Question is what code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core API isn't really designed for the scenario, but if you want to do this anyways, you'll need to repeat the logic that "dotnet-ef.dll" does to gather project context and compilation output, and then instantiate and use `MigrationsOperations` manually.

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Core/Design/MigrationsOperations.cs and https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/Internal/OperationExecutor.cs

Use caution: these are "Internal" APIs, which means their usage may break from version to version. "dotnet ef" is going to change a great deal between the current release (1.0.0-preview2) and the next release. (For example, the entire tooling implementation will change. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5334).

Comment: Thanks. Already digged there, but it'll be like another project to do that. Strange they didn't didn't come up with some facade class with several methods that copy all the functionality that `ef`command does.